# Query does not find persisted object in same transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, persistence, jdo

I've got domain objects that look like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class UserData implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Persistent
    @NotNull
    private String openId;

    public UserData(String openId)
    {
        this.openId = openId;
    }
}
```

Now I create a UserData object and make it persistent using JDO:

```
UserData userData = ThreadLocalPMF.getPersistenceManager().makePersistent(new UserData(openId));
```

A little bit later in the code I do a query in the same still open transaction, using the same PersistenceManager, same thread:

```
Query query = ThreadLocalPMF.getPersistenceManager().newQuery(UserData.class, "openId == :openId");
query.setUnique(true);
UserData userData = (UserData)query.execute(openId);
```

Now it happened once that the query did return null instead of the object that was made persistent some lines of code earlier. What's the problem here? Is this a consistency problem? The app is using the High Replication Datastore with

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When persisting an object with an id variable marked with:

```
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
```

I'm not 100% sure at the moment it will save the object with the provided ID. But I reckon it will save the object with a whole different ID value since it's following a `valueStrategy`.

To fix that, **after saving the object**, get it's ID before returning from the method, keep the ID to look up the object later on.

Answer (score 0):

In a GAE transaction, all queries within the transaction see a snapshot of the datastore state when the transaction started.  Queries will not return any new or updated entities that were modified within the transaction, you'll have to keep track of that yourself.

You should go back to the documentations for transactional queries to get more details.